# Angular component css does not make any changes

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

I am trying the simpliest styling and already failing. Fist list item does not respect "done" class and text is not changing. Although in inspect element i can see this style is added:

[image]

***app.component.html***

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ol>
        <li class="done">Add A button</li>
        <li>Add a paragraph</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***app.component.css***

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: This works on [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxymqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.ts) the problem seems to be someplace else.

Comment: Using dev tools if you select the element you can look for two things: 1) Under styles do you actually see any rules in your class? 2) If you look at computed then look for `text-decoration` do you see any values overriding this? You could always add a temporary `!important` to check for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as intended, see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wqqeeh?file=src/app/app.component.html) for reference.

Make sure that no other style rules interfere with this one when you inspect the element and/or try to add `!important` if you need to overwrite a previous style rule.

Comment: can bootstrap attached in angular.json meesing with me?

Comment: @gipcu That was a thought of mine too, but I tried adding it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmevuh?file=src/app/app.component.html) and the line-through still displays as expected.